# How can I set up nested routes in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, routes

I have some routes in Angular2

```
{ path: 'items', component: ItemComponent }
```

ItemComponent has it's own submenu.

```
<a routerLink='/items/sales'>Sales</a>
<a routerLink='/items/suppliers'>Suppliers</a>
<a routerLink='/items/stock'>Stock</a>
```

I want the submenu to be visible in all of those components (sales, suppliers, stock)

I'm trying to put a second router-outlet in the ItemComponent, which should then show sales / suppliers / stock. The reason is I want the submenu to be visible on all of these.

How can I set up nested routes like this?

Or should I instead just create an ItemMenuComponent and put an element for that at the top of sales, suppliers and stock components?

Comment: Are sales, suppliers and stock ItemComponents? because their route `items/sales` conflict with `items/:id`

Comment: You're right - that parameter shouldn't be in there for this example. Ultimately I'm intending to have the id parameter in there somewhere, but it's the child routing I was trying to figure out. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may define children routes like this.

```
[    
    {
        path: 'items',
        component: ItemsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '', // default
                component: SubItemComponent1
            },
            {
                path: 'item1',
                component: SubItemComponent1
            },
            {
                path: 'item2',
                component: SubItemComponent1
            }
        ]
    },
    ....
    ....
]
```

For more: https://github.com/narainsagar/angular2-demos/blob/master/src/app/app.routes.ts#L17

Cheers,

Comment: Interesting, I had wondered if the children property was relevant, but documentation is a bit thin at the moment! Does this all operate against a single router outlet?

Comment: OK that's a lot more detailed than it used to be! Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious :)

Comment: Have a look at this as well. It has a demo covered for sub routes: https://github.com/narainsagar/angular2-demos

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look!